# Can Spoils be trashed by Counterfeit?

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages

I'm looking for an authoritative answer here. Where does the Spoils card end up after being played twice by Counterfeit?

In fact, can Spoils be trashed at all? My understanding is that yes it can when it isn't played, e.g. in order to increase the value of Forager.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spoils is played twice, but is **returned to the Spoils pile and not trashed**.

Spoils is a treasure providing three coins that reads:

> When you play this, return it to the Spoils pile.

Counterfeit reads:

> When you play this, you may play a Treasure from your hand twice. If you do, trash that Treasure.

According to the Dark Ages rulebook ([PDF](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_421_gameRules.pdf)), page 11:

> If you use Counterfeit to play Spoils twice, you will get [six coins], (in addition to the [one coin] from Counterfeit) and return Spoils to the Spoils pile; you will be unable to trash it.

To answer your second question, Spoils can be trashed, but not when it is played, exactly as you expect.

Comment: From what you described, it sounds like Spoils cannot be trashed, so I'm confused by your last statement. Can you give some examples of how/what cards can trash a Spoils?

Comment: @Jeremy Sure. *Playing* a Spoils will return it to the pile, which means that trashing effects that happen after it's played (e.g. Counterfeit's) will "lose track" of the Spoils since it's moved from where it's *expected* to be. Other effects, such as Chapel which trash card(s) from your hand, can be used on Spoils, as well as attacks like Thief (which targets others' treasures) or Remodel (trash-for-benefit). Generally speaking, any trash effect that occurs without/before playing Spoils will work as expected.